# Route [product.store] not defined in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

before this, i just only have seller can create new product and it functions well there is no error

so for now, i add seller can create new category it functions but for seller create new product not function

it show Route [product.store] not defined. how i can fix it?

this is in web.php

```
Route::get('/index', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('/create', 'ProductController@create'); 
Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');  
Route::get('/category/index', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/category/create', 'CategoryController@create');
Route::post('','CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');
```

when i comment at //Route::post('','CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');seller can create new product it function but seller cannot create new category

this is product/create.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @include('admin.includes.sidebar_admin')
         <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Create products</div>
      <div class="panel-body">


       <form action="{{route('product.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}
         @csrf
```

this is category/create.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @include('admin.includes.sidebar_admin')
         <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Create New Category</div>
      <div class="panel-body">


       <form action="{{route('category.store')}}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
         @csrf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming of the routes is okay, but then you will have to provide an endpoint because that's what is actually used. You cannot post to the same endpoint and expect two different results..

so this:

```
Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

Can be this instead:

```
Route::post('/products','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

And this:

```
Route::post('','CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');
```

Can be :

```
Route::post('/categories','CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `web.php` you have two routes that overlap.

```php
Route::get('/index', 'ProductController@index');
Route::get('/create', 'ProductController@create'); 
Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');  //<----first one
Route::get('/category/index', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/category/create', 'CategoryController@create');
Route::post('','CategoryController@store')->name('category.store'); //<----second one
```

Change the route of the second one to something else like:

```
Route::post('/category','CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your way of declaring the route name in `web.php` file. You're overriding your product storing route with category store route.

```
Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');  
Route::post('','CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');
```

For a moment you might think their route name is different, so why they are not working. The point behind not working is the route name offers some particular advantages. Let's say you want to change the route to something like 'product/create'. Then you have to change them all over your project. If they are used 5 times, you have to change them 5times, if 50 times or more than that, I hope you can guess how much pain that would be. To get relief from that, the route name is here. Where you can give a name to route and call/refer them with their name. As a result in future if you change the route to something else you don't need to bother changing the reference as the name is still going to be the same.  But note that, ***route name*** or ***route*** can not refer or point to same **http verbs**. Here you broke the rules, Though your route name is different, you are pointing same route with same http verbs (**POST**). That's why it's overriding the previous one `Route::post('','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');` with the last one `Route::post('','CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');`. So for that route name product.store in unknown to Laravel.

*Some other minor corrections:* By default, the index file/method get fired. So you might want to replace them

```
//Route::get('/', 'ProductController@index')
Route::get('/index', 'ProductController@index');  
//Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@index')
Route::get('/category/index', 'CategoryController@index');
```